# rotate an Object, but translate the Object always in its own front Axis

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, transformation

I want to program a racinggame for Android. My Problem is, that if I rotate the car and want to translate the position it doesn't translate into the new direction of the car , but always in the X axis of the world.

Here is my wrong code.. thank you

```
gl.glTranslatef(car.position.x, car.position.y, car.position.z);

gl.glRotatef(car.currentAngle, 0, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have the solution. All I have to do is to translate my Car towards the new directional vector who gets changed by the new angle of my car :)

```
if (accel < 0)
    position.add((float) Math.sin(current * Math.PI/180)/5, 0, (float) Math.cos(currentangle * Math.PI/180)/5);
if (accel > 0)
    position.sub((float) Math.sin(current * Math.PI/180)/5, 0, (float) Math.cos(currentangle * Math.PI/180)/5);
```

and in the rendering class

```
gl.glTranslatef(car.position.x, car.position.y, car.position.z);
gl.glRotatef(car.currentAngle, 0, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Opengl uses matrices to create images.

In Matrices, multiplication do not have an associative property. Therefore when you rotate an object and then translate it, the object will end up in a different position as opposed if you did not translate it first.

A solution to transforming and translating an object would be to animate and translate. That way you can translate anywhere you want without worrying about object rotation's associative property.

To see the effects of the non-associative multiplication on your object, try this: rotate and translate your object about 8 times, rotating and translating 8 times each respectively. You will notice that your object will disappear. As opposed to "rotate in a circle while changing position".

Comment: wouldn't be a solution to rotate the whole world in the oppsite angle?

Comment: @m4tz3m4tz3 You will still need to animate your car to show that your car is turning. Otherwise your game won't be properly animated.